# Lightbox "next" and "prev" how?

Tags: javascript, php, css, gallery, lightbox

I would like to expand the Lightbox gallery of a **"next" button** and a **"prev" button**. Please help!

Listing:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE gal='$gallery' ORDER BY id ASC");
while ($galrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('underlay').style.display='block'; document.getElementById('lightbox').style.display='block'; document.getElementById('lightbox-img').src = 'gal/<?php echo $gallery . '/' . $galrow ['image']; ?>';">
<?php
echo '<img src="gal/' . $gallery . '/' . $galrow['image'] . '" />';
?>
</a>

<?php
}
?>
```

Show:

```
<div id="underlay">

</div>

<div id="lightbox">
<img src="" alt="" id="lightbox-img"/>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('underlay').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('lightbox').style.display='none';">X</a>

<a href="?">Next button</a>
<a href="?">Prev button</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried it myself, but I believe. the easiest way would be to move the original `next` and `previous` buttons with CSS to your desired location. Then just change the look of it and there you go.

Here looks like a good start on how to do that: http://answers.squarespace.com/questions/4375/how-can-i-customize-the-next-and-previous-buttons-in-the-lightbox-gallery-mode

Comment: It's too complicated for me. I need me some javascript and solutions. According to a new ID or a while loop, the button. Unfortunately, no not at all coming together. But thank you.